# Best method to get current user vote type for hundreds posts with Rails

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, voting

What's the best method to show user his vote type (for/against/abstain) on page with lots of post items?

direct query is

```sql
SELECT vote_type FROM votes WHERE post_id = 888 AND user_id = 888
```

and direct way with rails

```rb
post.votes.where(:user_id => current_user.id).pluck(:vote_type).first
```

but it's too heavy and stupid to make db query for every post.

I can build array of posts_id and make one query

```rb
@posts.each do |post|
  ids << post.id
end
votes = Vote.select(:post_id, :vote_type).where(:user_id => current_user.id, :post_id => ids)
```

```sql
SELECT post_id, vote_type FROM votes WHERE user_id = 888 AND post_id IN (887, 888, 889)
```

Is there built-in "magick" methods in rails? I use postgresql.

**UPD**
+1 same write method

```rb
current_user.votes.find_by_post_id(post.id)
```

**UPD2**
[Dummy-table on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=MTgCrp6M)

Comment: Looks like you're looking for eager loading of associations. If you could post your model associations as well as your controller action it would be possible to give you a complete query. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: Yes, that's it. Models assoc is simple: User(has_many: posts, votes), Post(belongs_to: user, has_many: votes), Vote(belongs_to: post, user).   what is better - 1000 partially cached(?) small queries or 1 large query with IN (1..1000)?

Comment: @depa, something like this? `@posts = Post.includes(:votes).where("votes.user_id" => current_user.id)` But this returns only posts with votes and makes *scary* SQL query.

Comment: Yeah, that should be it. Do you need data from any other tables other than `posts` and `votes`?

Comment: @depa, i need all posts from all users and information about current users vote type for each post if vote exists

Comment: It seems the vote type is a column in the `votes` table. So, it looks like you're set. That query you posted looks OK. Don't worry too much about the scary part. The important thing is to check if you're only running 2 queries for the whole page, rather than a new one for each individual vote. I highly recommend the bullet gem for that: https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet

Comment: thanks, but my query returns only post with current user votes, not all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
votes = Post.
  joins(:user).
  joins("LEFT JOIN votes ON votes.post_id = posts.id AND votes.user_id = 1").
  select("posts.id, posts.title, users.id AS users_id, votes.vote_type")
```

with a

```
votes.map {|p| [p.id, p.title, p.users_id, p.vote_type] }
```

I get

```
[[1, "Say hello", 1, nil], [2, "Amazing world", 2, 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you, oldschool way usually works :) I think, there is no built-in methods (like associations eg.) to make this in rails?

Answer (score 0):

```
@posts = Post.all.includes(:votes).where(posts: { user_id: current_user.id })
```

Comment: this gets all posts with ALL votes, not only current user votes. I need something like this `(Post.all) + (includes(:votes).where(:user_id => current_user.id))`

Comment: I think, the problem is in condition. If you use only includes - all posts will load, but if you use inclides with conditions, there's will be only posts which includes votes which match conditions

Comment: nope. nope. nope. Not about that. I am user, i want to see page with all posts of any users. I'm voting for one of posts and after page reload i want to know how i vote. Like here, you can vote for my comment and you will see your vote type after page will reload.